# Assignment error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am not able fix the error in this program. The error in this program is in the line:

```
mx(mslen+1:length(mx))=r;
```

> ???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
>  I must be the same.
>
> Error in ==> oo at 25
> mx(mslen+1:length(mx))=r;

The program is

```
clc;
clear all;
en=[1 0 0 0 0 0 0; ...   
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1; ...
    1 1 0 0 0 0 0; ...
    1 0 1 0 1 0 1; ...
    1 1 1 1 0 0 0; ...
    1 1 0 0 1 1 0; ...
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0; ...
    1 1 0 0 0 1 1; ...
    0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
m=en;
mslen=length(m);
patlen=input('\n Enter the length of the pattern : '); 

p(1:patlen)=1; 
p(2:patlen-1)=randint(1,patlen-2); 
mx=m; 
mx(mslen+1:mslen+patlen-1)=0; 
temp=mx(1:patlen); 
x=patlen; 
g=1; 
while(x<length(mx)+1) 
    r(1:patlen-1)=xor(temp(2:patlen),g*p(2:patlen)); 
    temp=r; 
    if x<(mslen+patlen-1) 
        temp(patlen)=mx(x+1); 
        g=r(1); 
    end 
    x=x+1; 
end 
mx(mslen+1:length(mx))=r; 
disp(sprintf('\n\n The transmitted frame is : ')); 
disp(sprintf('%d',mx)); 
temp=0; 
rx=mx; 
rx(randint(1,1,[1,length(rx)]))=randint(1,1); 
rx(randint(1,1,[1,length(rx)]))=randint(1,1); 
temp=rx(1:patlen); 
x=patlen; 
g=1; 
while(x<length(rx)+1) 
   rr(1:patlen-1)=xor(temp(2:patlen),g*p(2:patlen)); 
   temp=rr; 
   if x<length(rx) 
       temp(patlen)=rx(x+1); 
       g=rr(1); 
   end 
   x=x+1; 
end 
disp(sprintf('\n\n The received frame is : ')); 
disp(sprintf('%d',rx)); 
if sum(rr)==0; 
    disp(sprintf('\n\n No error in the received frame : ')); 
    disp(sprintf('\n\n The received data is : \n')); 
    disp(sprintf('%d',rx(1:mslen))); 
else 
    disp(sprintf('\n\n Error in the received frame !!!\n')); 
end
```

Comment: how do i get rid of this error

Comment: >> size r

ans =

     1     1

Comment: >> size mx

ans =

     1     2

>> size m

ans =

     1     1

Comment: sorry, r is 1x1 matrix only

Comment: But `m=en` and `mx=m`! How you get size(m) [1 1]? You didn't modify those matrices.

Comment: am really sorry :( its 9x7 matrix both mx and m

Comment: size of m and mx is 9x7 matrix and size of r is 1x2 matrix if patlen=3

Comment: In matlab there is a difference between `size mx` (where `mx` is treated as a string - did you see it change color?) and `size(mx)` (where it is treated as a variable). Indeed, `'r'` is a string of length 1, and `'mx`' is a string of length 2. That explains at least some of the weirdness in these comments.

Comment: @Floris: Smart detective work! I'd vote for answer as well once it confirmed to be true guess. :)

Comment: @yuk - thank you. I see good solutions from you all the time, too...

Comment: @yuk - it appears my answer worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following change makes your code run... because it guarantees that things on both sides of the expression have the same size. Whether it makes sense I leave up to you to figure out:

```
mx(mslen+(1:numel(r)) = r;
```

When I do this and run your code, it shows a transmitted frame and a received frame with one bit difference, and the message "Error in the received frame !!!"

I suspect this is your solution.

Comment: As promised. Nice job.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear: the size of `mslen+1:length(mx)` expression has to be equal to the size of `r`.

The usage of `length` is quite dangerous. It always returns the size of largest dimension. It can be number of rows or number of columns. It's safer to use `size(m,1)` for rows and `size(m,2)` for columns.

The variable `mslen` is the length of `m`, and you had `mx=m`. This means when you do `mslen+1:length(mx)` you get empty matrix, since `mslen+1` is larger than `length(mx)`.

There is something wrong with your algorithm and you cannot get rid of the error without reviewing your code.